# Focus Binding not set

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to implement an "Open File..." dialog in my Swift UI application. Most of it is working, but I am having trouble to synchronise the data between the command and the actually view. So far my I could figure out I have to use focus bindings.

My binding

```
struct FileFocusedValueKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<URL>
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var openedFile: FileFocusedValueKey.Value? {
        get {
            return self[FileFocusedValueKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[FileFocusedValueKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

In my command struct and view I've added

```
@FocusedBinding(\.openedFile) var file: URL?
```

The command writes it into the file binding, but the next time the view gets focused it is still empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I access the bindings like any other variable. My command

```
struct MenuCommands : Commands {
    /// Focus Binding for the current opened file. Nil if no file is selected
    @FocusedBinding(\.openedFile) var file: URL?
    /// If the file importer should be shown or not
    @State private var showFileImporter = false

    var body : some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.importExport) {
            Button("open") {
                showFileImporter = true
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("o")
            .fileImporter (
                isPresented: $showFileImporter,
                allowedContentTypes: [ UTType(exportedAs: "org.matroska.mkv", conformingTo: .movie) ],
                allowsMultipleSelection: false) {
                    result in switch result {
                    case .success(let files):
                        let file = files[0]
                        let gotAccess = file.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                        if !gotAccess { return }
                        
                        // Do Stuff
                        self.file = file
                        
                        file.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        // handle error
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view

```
struct Metadata: View {
    @FocusedBinding(\.openedFile) var file: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(file == nil ? "no_file_selected" : "\(file!.absoluteString)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the provided code on how you substitute the value for the `var file`. If you need a persistent value there you should map it with some @State variable or @Published in some view model.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my questions and added my code for the command and view. I have looked into `@State` and `@Published`, but would they also worked with multi window application?

Comment: I got it working :) It was a mix of `FocusedSceneBindings` and `States`. I had to change the `@FocusedBinding` in the View to a `@State` and add `.focusedSceneValue(\.openedFile, $file)` to the Text element.